# GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener and CDI (WildFly 8.2.0.Final / RESTEasy 3.0.10.Final / Guice 3.0)

Tags: cdi, guice, resteasy, wildfly

I recently had difficulty around Guice, CDI and RESTEasy. Does anyone have a similar experience or good solutions for this difficulty?

### Context

I tried to use Guice to DI a resource class in a RESTEasy (JAX-RS) application. It however failed to deploy when I just added GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.

The project had src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml. It was added to use some EJB-related features by other engineers. Removing beans.xml for trial eliminated the DeploymentException, but I cannot remove it from trunk.

This looks very similar to [Guava's past issue with CDI](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433), but I'm not sure how I can deal with it from the user side of RESTEasy. (I cannot modify RESTEasy to add 'bean-discovery-mode="none"' in RESTEasy.)

#### Update (Mar 15, 2015)

Just using @javax.ejb.Stateless with neither beans.xml nor javax.enterprise:cdi-api causes this issue.

---

See below for the minimum reproduction and the error message.

---

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foo</groupId><artifactId>guice-cdi-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version><packaging>war</packaging><name>Guice and CDI test</name>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Enabling this cdi-api or creating src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml will cause Weld's DeploymentException. -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId><artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId><artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId><artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId><artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### src/main/java/Application.java

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/")
public class Application extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {}
```

#### src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml

```
(empty file)
```

#### Error Message (in deployment)

```
20:19:49,332 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."guice-cdi-test-1.0.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."guice-cdi-test-1.0.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.parentInjector
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.parentInjector(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:372)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:293)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:531)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Mixing DI tools (CDI and guice) is a bad idea. You will always run into problems. Why can't you just work with CDI/weld?

Comment: It has already been mixed in other places, and it was better to choose Guice there to synchronize with the existing Guice. Hmm, but we may want to make all to CDI/Weld...

Comment: CDI itself is actually not used. beans.xml looks like imported for EJB- and DB-related resources (javax.ejb.EJB and javax.annotation.Resource). No javax.inject.* there.

I'm not sure beans.xml is actually required. (I'm not the person who added beans.xml...)

Comment: Found that just using @javax.ejb.Stateless causes this issue.